# Eliminar saltos de línea entre dos marcas

Tags: regex

El problema es que quiero reemplazar los saltos de línea (\r\n) entre dos marcas. Por ejemplo:

```html
hola <p> 123 456\r\n789\r\n123 456</p> adios
```

debe quedar como

```html
hola <p> 123 456 789 123 456</p> adios
```

el patrón que he empleado (el último y que tampoco funciona como deseo) es

```html
   "<p>\s+(\r\n)\s+</p>"
```

una ayudita, por favor

Vamos a ver si poniendo el código actual aclaro un poco

```
// C#
string html = "<html><body>hola\r\n<p> 123 456\r\n789\r\n123 456</p>\r\nadios</body></html>";
string patron = @"<p>+\s(\r\n)\s+</p>";                                 
string reemplazo = " ";                                                 
Regex rg = new Regex(patron);                                           
html = rg.Replace(html, reemplazo);                                     

// la intención es obtener:                                             
//<html><body>hola\r\n<p> 123 456 789 123 456</p>\r\n adios</body></html>
// por supuesto, habrá muchos párrafos <p>...</p>
```

Por si le vale a alguien pongo la solución de @ffflabs con el código en python para tratar los ficheros

```
from os import listdir
import re

def list_files(path, extension):
  return (f for f in listdir(path) if f.endswith(extension))

def repl(m):
  contents = m.group(0)
  return contents.replace('\n', ' ')

path = 'C:\html\Pyton'
extension = '.htm'
regex = r'<p>([\s|\S]*?)</p>'

files = list_files(path, extension)
for file in files:
  with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as inf:
    htm = ""
    linea = inf.readline()
    while linea:
      htm += linea
      linea = inf.readline()
    html = re.sub(regex, repl, htm)
    with open(file + 'l', 'w') as outf:
      outf.write(html)
```

Comment: Es posible que esté un poco desordenado el patrón... "<p>"+\s(\r\n)\s+"</p>", creo que sería algo así

Comment: @Fergush te animo a que escribas una respuesta con la explicación de esa expresión regular.

Comment: No pienso que sea una respuesta que solucione el problema que tiene el OP, simplemente he estructurado la expresión regular que ha puesto. Puede que sea correcta, pero esté mal formulada.

Comment: Pueden existir `<p>` anidados? Es decir, etiquetas `<p>` dentro de otras etiquetas `<p>`. Es posible?

Answer (score 1):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Si como parece necesitamos conservar los `\r\n` fuera de los párrafos `<p>`, asumiendo que el html está bien formado, o al menos tiene el mismo número de `<p>`y `</p>`, podemos hacer un reemplazo global con el siguiente código:

```
let texto = 'hola\r\n<p> 123 456\r\n789\r\n123 456</p>\r\n adios <p> una\r\nlinea</p> más cosas';
let texto_formateado = '';
let i0 = texto.indexOf('<p>');
let i1 = 0;
while(i0 !== -1) {
    texto_formateado += texto.substring(i1, i0);
    i1 = texto.indexOf('</p>', i0);
    texto_formateado += texto.substring(i0, i1).replace(/\r\n/g, ' ');
    i0 = texto.indexOf('<p>', i1);
}
texto_formateado += texto.substring(i1);
```

El texto resultante en `texto_formateado` sería:

```
'hola\r\n<p> 123 456 789 123 456</p>\r\n adios <p> una linea</p> más cosas'
```

RESPUESTA ORIGINAL:

No veo en el código el sitio donde se aplica la expresión regular, pero si suponemos que el texto llega en una variable llamada `texto`, sería tan sencillo como aplicar la siguiente sentencia:

```
 var texto = '123 456\r\n789\r\n123 456';
 var texto_formateado = texto.replace(/\r\n/g, ' ');
```

El resultado almacenado en `texto_formateado` sería el esperado:

```
 '123 456 789 123 456'
```

Comment: Gracias, pero voy a mejorar el ejemplo, la cadena 'hola\r\p<p> 123 456\r\n789\r\n123 456</p>\r\padios'; debe quedar como 'hola\r\p<p> 123 456 789 123 456</p>\r\padios'. Solo deben reemplazarse los saltos de líneas entre las marcas. El método replace de string sería el más sencillo, no haría falta regex si fuera quitar todos.

Comment: ¿ Puede haber más de 1 bloque con `<p> ... </p>` ?

Comment: Si, por supuesto, es una página HTML

Comment: Voy a extenderme más en los comentarios: Si, es una página HTML y por supuesto, puede, y de hecho hay, múltiples párrafos <p>...</p>, y la intención es eliminar todos los saltos de líneas en el texto entre <p> y </p> dejando el resto del fichero HTML sin tocar.

Comment: Ok, @JLPrieto, he actualizado la respuesta con la nueva info.

Comment: Gracias, pero mi intención es utilizar Regex, para hacerlo con string.replace no habría puesto la pregunta.

Comment: Ok, eso no lo dices en la pregunta, :-(,  dejo la respuesta por si algún otro usuario pueda necesitarla por un caso similar, por favor, la próxima vez se más explicito en la pregunta, así podremos ayudarte mejor el resto de usuarios. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

esto probablemente es una solución horrible pero es menos artesanal que explotar y joinear en varios pasos.

Mi texto será el siguiente

```
const parrafo = `Santiago, 12 de febrero 2020.\r\nQuerida abuelita:\r\n <p> Cómo estás?\r\nYo muy bien.\r\nSaludos a todos. </p> \r\n Cariños, Carlos.`;
```

**Expresiones de Captura**

En rigor la pregunta habla de `<p><espacio><texto><espacio></p>` pero voy a simplificarme la vida y diré que los espacios son parte del grupo.

Como el texto tiene saltos de línea y `.*` no pasa de una línea a otra, vamos a usar `[\s|\S]*` que sí captura todo.

Dicho esto, lo que está contenido entre `<p>` y `</p>` puede obtenerse con la expresión:

```
 const regex = /<p>([\s|\S]*?)<\/p>/g
```

**Función de Reemplazo**

A la hora de reemplazar, el segundo parámetro de  `String.prototype.replace` puede ser una string, otra expresión regular, o *una función* con el footprint

```
     function (all, p1,...,pn, offset, string_original) { ... }
```

Donde all es toda la cadena que hizo match, `p1` a `pn` los grupos de captura y el resto ya se lo imaginarán. En este caso, sólo hay un grupo de captura por lo que

- `all` es `<p>texto</p>`
- `p1` es sólo `texto`

El reemplazo que yo usaría entonces es

```js
const parrafo = `Santiago, 12 de febrero 2020.\r\nQuerida abuelita:\r\n <p> Cómo estás?\r\nYo muy bien.\r\nSaludos a todos. </p> \r\n Cariños, Carlos.`;
const regex = /<p>([\s|\S]*?)<\/p>/g

let replaced = parrafo.replace(regex,(all) => {
  return all.replace(/\r\n/g,' ');
});

console.log(replaced);
```

## Múltiples párrafos

Definimos un segundo párrafo:

```
const  segundo_parrafo=`Momento!\r\n <p> Se me olvidaba pedirte algo:\r\nenvíame dinero\r\n gracias!! </p> \r\n ahora sí, adiós` ;
```

Y probamos

```js
const parrafo = `Santiago, 12 de febrero 2020.\r\nQuerida abuelita:\r\n <p> Cómo estás?\r\nYo muy bien.\r\nSaludos a todos. </p> \r\n Cariños, Carlos.`;
const  segundo_parrafo=`Momento!\r\n <p> Se me olvidaba pedirte algo:\r\nenvíame dinero\r\n gracias!! </p> \r\n ahora sí, adiós` ;

const regex = /<p>([\s|\S]*?)<\/p>/g

let replaced = [parrafo,segundo_parrafo].join('\n').replace(regex,(all) => {
  return all.replace(/\r\n/g,' ');
});

console.log(replaced);
```

Ver solución en [<kbd>Observable HQ</kbd>](https://observablehq.com/d/52ca4f851e93f8af)

**Edit:**

Lo importante es que acá hay que extraer el grupo de captura y **operar** sobre él. Pienso que la "traducción" a otros lenguajes no es evidente.

Por ejemplo en PHP no serviría `preg_replace` sino que hay que usar `preg_replace_callback` [<kbd>ver en 3v4l.org</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/Dtnar)

```
<?php

$parrafo         = "Santiago, 12 de febrero 2020.\r\nQuerida abuelita:\r\n <p> Cómo estás?\r\nYo muy bien.\r\nSaludos a todos. </p> \r\n Cariños, Carlos.";
$segundo_parrafo = "Momento!\r\n <p> Se me olvidaba pedirte algo:\r\nenvíame dinero\r\n gracias!! </p> \r\n ahora sí, adiós";

$replaced = preg_replace_callback(
    ' /<p>([\s|\S]*?)<\/p>/',
    function ($coincidencias) {
        return str_replace("\r\n", ' ', $coincidencias[0]);
    },
    implode(PHP_EOL, [$parrafo, $segundo_parrafo])
);
echo $replaced;
```

En python, `re.sub` permite pasar una función en lugar del pattern:

```
import re

def repl(m):
    contents = m.group(0)
    return contents.replace('\r\n','')

regex = r"<p>([\s|\S]*?)</p>"
parrafo = "Santiago, 12 de febrero 2020.\r\nQuerida abuelita:\r\n <p> Cómo estás?\r\nYo muy bien.\r\nSaludos a todos. </p> \r\n Cariños, Carlos"
parrafo+="\n Momento!\r\n <p> Se me olvidaba pedirte algo:\r\nenvíame dinero\r\n gracias!! </p> \r\n ahora sí, adiós"

sub=re.sub(regex, repl, parrafo)
print(sub)
```

[<kbd>ver en repl.it</kbd>](https://repl.it/@ffflabs/EuphoricGratefulFlashdrives)

No sé cómo se hace en Java y nunca he visto una linea de C#

Comment: el ejemplo de la abuelita lol

Comment: Gracias @ffflabs. Estoy intentando poner tu respuesta en C#, pero algo me patina. Puedes decirme como quedaría en C#?

Comment: no sé cómo se haría. Puse la versión python y php

Comment: Gracias @ffflabs. He preparado un script en python. Funciona si modifico tu función con: return contents.replace('\n', ' ')  al trabajar en windows parece que le basta con '\n' para el salto de página. No me estaba funcionando con '\r\n', que es lo que contienen los ficheros. Procesaré todos los ficheros con el código de python y despues pasarán a los procesos generales. Diremos aquello de: si no puedes hacerlo dentro hazlo fuera, pero hazlo. Gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

1. removería todos los **\r** y **\n**.
2. al final de los **p** agregaría los elementos.

```js
var str = 'hola\r\n<p> 123 456\r\n789\r\n123 456</p>\r\n adios <p> una\r\nlinea</p> más cosas';
var new_str = str.replace(/\r\n/g,' ').replace(/\/p>/g,'\/p>\r\n');
console.log(str.replace(/\r\n/g,' ').replace(/\/p>/g,'\/p>\r\n'));
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que no puedas encontrar etiquetas `<p>` anidadas, se podría hacer con una expresión regular y sin necesidad de código adicional.

Además, esta solución permite que las etiquetas `<p>` puedan tener atributos (como en `<p class="miclase">`)

Prueba buscando:

```
(?-m)(?si)((?:\G(?!^)|<p\b[^>]*>)(?:(?!<\/p>).)*?)[\r\n]+
```

Remplazar por (en C#):

```
$1
```

Tienes un ejemplo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/KXBraz/3/). En el ejemplo se usa `\1` para remplazar porque trabaja con php. Pero en tu caso, para C# deberías usar `$1`.

Puedes probar la expresión regular para C# insertando el mismo caso en esta [otra utilidad](http://regexstorm.net/tester).